# How can I make invalid numbers not add to my end calculations and counter total?

Tags: java

My issue comes up when I enter an number where i have the illegal score prompt, it still adds a number to my counter and the number to the total so the average gets thrown off.  Ive been wracking my brain and tried almost everything to figure it out.  The code is a little sloppy because I haven't cleaned it up yet, I'm just trying to get the moving parts sorted out first.

```
public class StudentSentinel {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double score;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average;
    int scoreCount = 0;

    // create the Scanner object. Name it stdin
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    // title at the top of the output
    System.out.println(" student score report");;

    //   read the first score
    System.out.printf("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)" +
      ": ", scoreCount);

    score = stdin.nextDouble();
    scoreCount++;

    while (score != -1.0) {

      total += score;
      System.out.printf("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)" +
        ": ", scoreCount);
      scoreCount++;
      score = stdin.nextDouble();
      if (score < -1)
        System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
      else if (score > 100) {
        System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
      }
      // increment the loop counter
    }
    // end of for loop
    average = total / scoreCount;
    System.out.printf("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
      scoreCount, average);
  } // end of main    
} // end of class definition
```

Answer (score 3):

First check that the score is legal, then increment the counter and add it to your `total`. You can also assign `score` and check that isn't `-1` with a single operation. And always use braces (even if they're optional). Like,

```
// read the first score
System.out.printf("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)" + ": ", scoreCount);
while ((score = stdin.nextDouble()) != -1.0) {
    if (score < -1 || score > 100) {
        System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
    } else {
        scoreCount++;
        total += score;
    }
    System.out.printf("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)" + ": ", scoreCount);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this made a lot of sense and helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code out. It works for me:

```
public class StudentSentinel  {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    double score;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average;
    int scoreCount = 0;

    // create the Scanner object. Name it stdin
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    // title at the top of the output
    System.out.println(" student score report");;

    //   read the first score
    System.out.printf("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)" +
            ": ", scoreCount);

    score = stdin.nextDouble();
    scoreCount++;
    total += score;
    while (score != -1.0) {


        System.out.printf("Enter a score  (1-100, -1 to quit)" +
                ": ", scoreCount);
        scoreCount++;
        score = stdin.nextDouble();
        if (score < -1) {
            System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
            continue;
        }else if (score > 100) {
            System.out.println("Illegal score.  Try again");
            continue;
        }
        total += score;
        // increment the loop counter
    }
    // end of for loop
    average = total / scoreCount;
    System.out.printf("\nThe average score for %d students is %8.2f\n",
            scoreCount, average);
} // end of main
```

}

Comment: I saved this to go over.  Thank you for taking the time

Comment: Okay @Moca , Just try this out and let me know if This worked for you or not

Comment: it did work out thank you.  If I wanted to add a part where the user could enter a number before the loop starts to just end it before any calculations would made.  You add that before the while right?

Comment: Can you elaborate this, what exactly you want to do? And if you find previous answer useful please accept this as answer to your ques, thank you

Comment: Like before the loop.  I want to add a do task that gives the option that the user enters a -1 and it gives a message "nothing was entered".  I got the first part of it, but I can't get the do to loop in to the while

Comment: Okay, what you can do is after score = stdin.nextDouble(); statement which is before the while loop, you can add this piece of code `while(score == -1)
 { System.out.println("Nothing was entered"); 
System.out.printf("Enter a score (1-100, -1 to quit)" + ": ", scoreCount);
 score = stdin.nextDouble(); }` After this you can continue with same code

Comment: @Moca if my answer above helped you just accept this as answer to you question. It will help me in getting repo